# Holding torques of a 7W stepper and a 48W stepper

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor, torque

Does anyone know why a 2.5V 2.8A (=7W) [stepper](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-23-stepper-motor-l56mm-gear-raio-501-high-precision-planetary-gearbox-23hs22-2804s-hg50.html) has a holding torque of 1Nm whilst a 24V 4A (=48W) [stepper](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1317040/SanyoDenki/103H7823-5740/1) has a holding torque of only 2.7Nm:

Stepper 1:

[image]

Stepper 2:

[image]

The latter draws 7x the power, but gives just 2x the holding torque. The inductances are roughly the same. The first is 2.8mH and the latter is 2.4mH. What might cause a 48W stepper to draw so much more power but give so little more?

Comment: Optimized for different applications, probably. Sometimes you want torque, sometimes you want speed, other times you want holding torque. Or efficiency, or smaller size, or reaction speed. Could be anything, really.

Comment: Why are you comparing such completely different motors with each other in the first place?

Comment: @Mast By completely different, what do you mean? They're both bipolar steppers, but one's 24V and one's 2.5V.

Comment: The voltage and rated current difference alone makes them completely different motors. Just because the basic idea is the same, doesn't make them comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Pictures from [here](https://www.machinedesign.com/mechanical-motion-systems/article/21125066/increasing-step-motor-torque-without-increasing-frame-size#:~:text=Larger%20frame%20size%20step%20motors,in%20an%20application's%20limited%20space.&text=To%20build%20a%20step%20motor,together%2C%20thus%20the%20increased%20length.).

In short, the longer the stack-length the more torque can be produced per amp. So, if the basic model can take more current, it can generate more torque AND if its stack length is longer it can produce even more torque.

It's got nothing to do with the electrical power fed to the stepper motor when stalled - all that power is just wasted. After all, a bench vice doesn't consume power when gripping a motor armature to a standstill and, all the power fed to the stepper motor is turned to heat in a rotor lock situation.

Current and length are the primary factors for torque.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why a 2.5V 2.8A (=7W) stepper has a holding torque of
>   1Nm whilst a 24V 4A (=48W) stepper has a holding torque of only 2.7Nm:

Torque is proportional to current. The stepper motor with a higher rated current is producing higher torque. There is more todo with this, ie number of windings, length of the rotor but generally as a 1st pass reasoning this is valid